# VBA - How can I give an error code based on the sum of my textbox values ina user form?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, textbox, userform

So I currently have a userform with 3 input boxes and a save button.
The three inputs have to be between 0.0 and 1.0, which is what I have done using the code below.

I now need the sum of those 3 inputs to equal 1. If the sum of those inputs is not equal to 1 I want to display an error message upon the click of the save button.

Really stuck on this and have tried a couple of different methods which havent worked.

Is there any way to do this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim textbox1 As Integer
Dim textbox2 As Integer
Dim textbox3 As Integer

On Error GoTo errHandler
textbox1 = CInt(UserForm1.textbox1.Value)
If textbox1 > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Input, Please enter value between 0.0 and 1.0"
Else
    UserForm1.Hide
End If

On Error GoTo errHandler
textbox2 = CInt(UserForm1.textbox2.Value)
If textbox2 > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Input, Please enter value between 0.0 and 1.0"
Else
    UserForm1.Hide
End If
Exit Sub

On Error GoTo errHandler
textbox3 = CInt(UserForm1.textbox3.Value)
If textbox3 > 1 Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Input, Please enter value between 0.0 and 1.0"
Else
    UserForm1.Hide
End If
Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried `IF` and `+` handling the `.hide`?

Comment: did you tried: `If (textbox1 + textbox2 + textbox3) = 1 Then`?

Comment: If the values have to be **between 0.0 and 1.0** you may want to rethink placing the values into Integer variables, which will make anything less than 0.50000 equal 0 and anything between 0.50000 and 1.49999 equal to 1. So 0.4 + 0.35 + 0.25 will be equivalent to 0 + 0 + 0 which won't sum to 1. (Perhaps use Double, or Currency if you don't allow more than 4 decimal digits.)

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to Currency and used the if statement and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took some liberties in answering your questions because I saw opportunities to improve your code versus just getting you to the answer. The code below should be easier to read/manage and I hope it will help you in writing better code in the future below. Code first, and then I will explain the process:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Inputs(1 To 3) As Variant
    Dim Total As Double

    ' It is better to anticipate errors (check the values that could cause an error) than it is to
    ' use a GoTo block that catches everything.
    ' On Error GoTo errHandler

    Inputs(1) = GetInputFromTextbox(UserForm1.textbox1)
    Inputs(2) = GetInputFromTextbox(UserForm1.textbox2)
    Inputs(3) = GetInputFromTextbox(UserForm1.textbox3)

    ' Handle the errors all in the same block (simply for readability)
    If IsEmpty(Inputs(1)) Then
        InvalidInput "Textbox1"
        UserForm1.Hide
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Inputs(2)) Then
        InvalidInput "Textbox2"
        UserForm1.Hide
    ElseIf IsEmpty(Inputs(3)) Then
        InvalidInput "Textbox3"
        UserForm1.Hide
    Else
        ' This will only execute if the three previous inputs are valid
        Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Inputs)
        If Total <> 1 Then
            TotalInputsInvalid Total
        End If
    End If

End Sub

' Define the function as a variant so it can return a null value
' This is important since the user could enter a 0 value and the default return of
' the function, if defined as a numeric type, would be 0. This would, in turn, prevent error handling.
Private Function GetInputFromTextbox(ByVal InputMember As Object) As Variant
    If IsNumeric(InputMember.Value) Then
        If CDbl(InputMember.Value) < 1 Then
            GetInputFromTextbox = Round(CDbl(InputMember.Value), 2)
        End If
    End If

    ' Notice that, if the conditions for a valid input are not met, nothing happens.
    ' This allows us to handle errors within the calling routine.
End Function



' This will alert the user if the input given is invalid.
Private Sub InvalidInput(ByVal MemberName As String)
    MsgBox "There is an invalid input in " & MemberName & ". Please enter value between 0.0 and 1.0."
End Sub


Private Sub TotalInputsInvalid(ByVal TotalValue As Double)
    MsgBox "The total value of all inputs must equal 1. The current total is " & Round(TotalValue, 2) & ". Please adjust the inputs accordingly."
End Sub
```

First of all, I have defined one variable for the input values. The main benefit to this is that your code is cleaner and makes more sense. Having variables such as Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, etc. makes your code a little bit messier. An array can make this process easier, especially if this application has to scale to accomodate more textboxes.

Also notice that, per YowE3k's suggestion, I have declared the array as an array of `double`s, and likewise with `Total`. `Double`s allow floating point precision whereas `Long`s and `Integer`s only allow whole numbers (sidenote on this, never use `Integer`. Get in the habit of only using Longs for anything you would use an Int for).

Next, I have defined a function that gets the clean input from the textbox. This is a good habit to get into. Keep in mind that a copy-paste now inevitably means additional debugging/fixing time later. There are rare cases where is it somewhat unavoidable for the current circumstances, but more often than not a Function or Sub will do wonders.

In the case of the function I have defined, it first checks for a numeric input (avoiding the Type Mismatch error) and then checks to ensure the value is not greater than 1. If both of these conditions succeed then it returns the value (rounded to the second decimal place), else it returns nothing.

I use this function to get all three values, and then I test the validity of all three values in the same If/ElseIf block. This will ensure all three values are valid before performing the final check.

In the final check, it ensures that the total is equal to 1, and if it is then nothing happens. If it isn't, it alerts the user that the inputs are invalid.

The process here is to use functions to return values, and then to use logic to handle errors. This is far more effective than GoTo blocks, and it makes debugging code much easier (at least in my experience).

If you have any questions, please ask. Best of luck!

**EDIT:** Changed declaration of Inputs from Double to Variant. The Double type automatically sets the base values to 0 versus allowing `Empty`. This in turn prevents checking invalid values vs. zeroes. The Variant type fixes this.

Comment: Thank you so much for going through that to help me out. Your code is indeed much cleaner and more logical. Your explanation also helped ALOT - I am quite new to VBA. Thank you!!!

Only problem I have when I replace my code with yours: It only adds the sum of the second decimal place - not the whole number. I'm attaching a photo so show you what I mean. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE6rL.jpg)

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @A.Desai Try the updated code (I just changed the declaration type of Inputs from `Double` to `Variant`). I hadn't realized that the default value of a `Double` array is 0 (in a `Variant` array it is `Empty`) and because of this, the invalid input check was satisfied by the 0, despite the input of 1.5 being invalid. You should now properly be alerted if you enter a number over 1.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. I tried the new code and it now works perfectly!! Thank you so much for all your help